# Conditionally import modules in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, rollup

I'm working on library for React with free and pro components with rollup for production and webpack for dev. I want to reuse one component but with less variations for free version. Code below was working so far, but if we think about ssr and tree-shaking support with rollup, we have to use es6 imports (at least so far as i know).
Any ideas how to import module if it exists -> if not - import another module?

```js
let DropdownMenuComponent;
try {
  DropdownMenuComponent = require("./pro/DropdownMenuProComponent").default;
} catch (err) {
  DropdownMenuComponent = require("./DropdownMenuComponent").default;
}
```

I have tried dynamic import, but it did not catch errors properly, while the module was missing.

Thanks

Comment: It is not within the class but on the top of the file where imports should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

actually there is a proposal at stage 3 for dynamically importing ES modules with import(), also the [babel presets are available](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/), in your case would be something like this:

```
if (isProAccount()) 
    import("./pro/DropdownMenuProComponent")
      .then(DropdownMenuComponent => DropdownMenuComponent.something());
else
    ...
```